# SqlParameter with default value set to 0 doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, sqlparameter

I was doing something like this:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@Param", 0) { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int };

private void TestParam(SqlParameter param) {
   string test = param.Value.ToString();  // Getting NullReferenceException here
}
```

But I stop getting the exception when I put it like this:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@Param", SqlDbType.Int)  { Value = 0 };

private void TestParam(SqlParameter param) {
    string test = param.Value.ToString();  // Everything OK
}
```

Can anyone tell me why SqlParameter assumes 0 is the same as null?

**Edit:** MSDN Explains this here: [SqlParameter Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, it is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y%28v=VS.80%29.aspx When creating a new SqlParameter with default value "0", you need to cast it explicitly to integer. Otherwise it assumes you're passing a SqlDbType enum as the second parameter.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> Use caution when you use this overload
>   of the SqlParameter constructor to
>   specify integer parameter values.
>   Because this overload takes a value of
>   type Object, you must convert the
>   integral value to an Object type when
>   the value is zero, as the following C#
>   example demonstrates.
>
> ```
> Parameter = new SqlParameter("@pname", Convert.ToInt32(0));
> ```
>
> If you do not perform this conversion,
>   the compiler assumes that you are
>   trying to call the SqlParameter
>   (string, SqlDbType) constructor
>   overload.

Thanks [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y.aspx) :)

Answer (score 8):

The 0 you are passing in is the ***type***, not the value. 0 literals (and constant values) are allowed for ***any*** enum type - meaning the 0 of the underlying enum type, and are a better "match" than object, since it doesn't need boxing.

Personally, I would use;

```
Value = 0
```

perhaps in the object initializer.